# Кэширование : cвязка nginx - ssi - memcache

Tags: nginx, кэширование, ssi

Так и не нашел на просторах интернета как работает связка ssi-memcache в подробностях.
Если инструкция `<!--# include virtual="/path" -->` понятно как работает  при обращении к php  скрипту (который может обработать Cookies или Session данные), то как получить нужный ключ для обращения к memcache? Где и как формируется нужный ключ Memcache? Об этом авторы статей обычно забывают сказать.